# Can we have $ \lim_{x \to f(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Can we have a limit where $x$ approaches a variable like this one:$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to f(x)}$ or $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \cos(x)}$ ? And why? Thank you!

Comment: What would it mean to say that$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to f(x)} g(x) = L$?

Comment: I don't know, can you explain it for me? I haven't studied anti-derivatives yet.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with anti-derivatives...

Comment: No...$g(x)$ here just means "some other function of $x$"

Comment: Thank you for the rectification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, one defines
$$\lim_{x\to a}y$$
only if

- $x$ is a variable
- $a$ is an expression not depending on $x$
- $y$ is an expression possibly depending on $x$

and defines it as the unique number $c$ (if it exists) such that 
$$\tag1 \forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0\forall x\in\mathbb R\colon (|x-a|<\delta\to|y-c|<\epsilon)$$
(where, to be formal again, $\delta,\epsilon$ are "new" variables not occuring in $x,a,y,c$).

However, by interpreting (1) very literally, one *might* interprete $\lim_{x\to f(x)}$ as taking the limit when e.g. $x$ tends to a fixpoint of a continuous function $f$. I have yet to see such a notion in the wild and doubt its usefulness (for example because $f$ might have several fixpoints and in fact $x\to f(x)$ might not even imply that $x$ converges in the first place)